# Hidden extra field in Excel after export from ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I get hidden extra fields in my report in Excel after export from SSRS.

There is only 1 table in report. All columns have same size.

SQL Server 2014, Report Builder 3.0

Please any help.

Kindly
Taty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UEmQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWGw3.png)

Comment: When you have headers that span across multiple columns. Exporting could result in `merged` columns.

Answer (score 1):

When we see extra fields in the Excel export it is usually because a text box not in the main tablix has an edge that does not align with the fields in the tablix. Make sure that all fields not in the tablix (including header and footer fields) have their edges aligned with a tablix field edge.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your report contains hidden columns.
Hidden Columns in your report are not removed, only hidden. so they get copied when you export to Excel.

Open the report in report builder and check if there are columns there that are not shown in the report.